# Вывод TV на всех страницах сайта

Tags: modx

Есть стандартная шапка сайта, там указаны телефон, email, ссылки на соц.сети.
Все данные выводятся через TV. Вопрос следующий.
Например для TV "телефон" в "Доступно для шаблонов" указана только главная страница (шаблон главной страницы). Получается на остальных шаблонах, данные не выводятся.
Если же в "Доступно для шаблонов" указать все шаблоны, то TV поля появляются на каждой странице, т.е. нужно каждый раз писать/вставлять эти данные для каждой страницы.

Есть ли способ один раз заполнить TV поле и выводить на все страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно указать TV где-то в одном месте и во всех других местах вызывать. Какие возможны варианты:

1. Назначить TV для одной страницы, например, главная, для других вызывать через [fastField](https://docs.modx.com/current/ru/extras/fastfield) или если используете fenom, то вот так(1 это ID главной страницы):

   {set $phone = 1 | resource: 'phone'}
2. Задать через системную переменную и выводить

   [[++phone]]

или используя fenom

```
{$_modx->config.phone}
```

3. Аналогичный вывод при использовании [ClientConfig](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/clientconfig)

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался 3 вариантом!